# ASP.Net WebApi Controller should return 204 instead of null [HttpResponseMessage]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I would like to have my Controllers return a HttpResponseMessage of 204 (NoContent), when i.e. the selected resource is not found.

Usually I code it like this:

```
public Contracts.IRoom Get(HttpRequestMessage request, int id)
        {
            return _RoomRepo.GetAllRooms().Where(r => r.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();            
        }
```

But this gives me a ResponseCode of 200 (Ok) and Data of `null`

So to achieve, what i am looking for, i have to code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request, int id)
{
    var room = _RoomRepo.GetAllRooms().Where(r => r.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (room != null)
        return request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, room);
    else
        return request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent, room);
}
```

Is there an easier way of doing this?
It seems like the asp.net guys might have already fixed this in MVC 6, as stated in [ASP.Net Docs](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-web-api.html)

Comment: Typically you would return 404 Not Found when the selected resource is not found; 204 No Content is usually used when you PUT or DELETE a resource and don't return any data. If your API is for internal consumption then your approach is probably OK, but if your API is being used by others, then you should either go with more idiomatic usage, or make sure your documentation is very clear that it is returning non-standard result codes.

Answer (score 2):

Web API engine doesn't create all types of responses by itself. In your case, it doesn't know the meaning of 'null', and even if you have multiple statements interacting with database, a few of them returning null and other returning some data. So there is no way for API to detect 'NoContent' in this case.

Actually you have to create response type by your own for the users who are consuming your api in a simple understandable way.

You are doing best, as it is the exact role of controller class.